# How to check whether biometric of fingerprint is already set up or not in phone

Tags: flutter, authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I use local_auth package of flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth/example) to authenticate fingerprint, so far when I use that package, it detects whether fingerprint is already set up or not (useErrorDialogs: true), if not it will show a pop up message to navigate user to setting to set it up and if it is already set up.. it will show pop op dialog to authenticate fingerprint directly... so here I do confused, is there a way to "only" check whether fingerprint is already set up or not in user's phone cell? here is part of the code that I have tried

```
authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate',
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as this package is concerned, no there is no way. You can look at the sourcecode in GitHub to find out yourself.

You can find out if the device is *capable* of biometrics, but not if the user has configured it correctly yet.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you have any idea to check the fingerprint setting is already set up or not using another method or package ?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try catch the `auth.authenticate` function which will return a PlatformException with that you can open settings by other plugin/packages

[image]